# Quote calculation increments all and not individual when clicking plus minus sign

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code here and its working fine, calculations are ok, the only issue here is that when I click the plus or minus sign it changes all, I have applied the .each() function but I think my coding is wrong or not in the right place, my code is below but I have this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Loktfa2b/ also for you guys to see the actual running script. Thank you guys for the help in advance :-)

Here are my codes

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content" style="display:flex;">
    <div id="mysliders">
        
        <div class="section-container calc-module slider1">
            <div><div for="slider-1">Testing 1</div></div>
            <div>
                <label for="slider-1"> <span class="help-info"></span></label>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="minus">-</button>
                        <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="0.10" max="50" step="0.10" value="1" />
                        <button id="plus">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>$<div id="slider-1-total"></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-container calc-module slider2">
            <div><div for="slider-2">Testing 2</div></div>                
            <div>
                <label for="slider-2"></label>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="minus">-</button>
                        <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" min="250" max="50000" step="250" value="1000" />
                        <button id="plus">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>$<div id="slider-2-total"></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-container calc-module slider3">
            <div><div for="slider-3">Testing 2</div></div>
            <div>
                <label for="slider-3"></label>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="minus">-</button>
                        <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-3" id="slider-3" min="0" max="100" step=".5" value="20" />
                        <button id="plus">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div><div id="slider-3-total"></div>%</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-container calc-module slider4">
            <div><div for="slider-4">Testing 3</div></div>
            <div>
                <label for="slider-4"></label>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="minus">-</button>
                        <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-4" id="slider-4" min="0" max="100" step=".5" value="40" />
                        <button id="plus">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div><div id="slider-4-total"></div>%</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-container calc-module slider5">
            <div><div for="slider-5">Testing 4</div></div>
            <div>
                <label for="slider-5"></label>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="minus">-</button>
                        <input class="add" type="range" name="slider-5" id="slider-5" min="0" max="100000" step="100" value="100" />
                        <button id="plus">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>$<div id="slider-5-total"></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        

    </div>
    
    <div class="right_calc">
        
        <div>

            
           
            
            <div class="roi-result-container"><div>Test 1</div><div><strong id="visit"></strong></div></div>
            <div class="roi-result-container"><div>Test 2</div><div><strong id="leads"></strong></div></div>
            <div class="roi-result-container"><div>Test 3</div><div>$<strong id="cpl"></strong></div></div>
            <div class="roi-result-container"><div>Test 4</div><div><strong id="sales"></strong></div></div>
            <div class="roi-result-container"><div>Test 5</div><div>$<strong id="revenue"></strong></div></div>
            <div class="roi-result-container" style="font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;"><div>Total</div><div><strong id="total"></strong>%</div></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

and here is my jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery( ".calc-module .add" ).each(function() {
            jQuery(this).on("change", function () {
                addAll();
            });
           

            addAll();
        });     
    });


    function addAll() {
        var sum = 0
        var slider1 = jQuery('.slider1 .add').val(); //visit
        var slider2 = jQuery('.slider2 .add').val(); //Leads
        var slider3 = jQuery('.slider3 .add').val(); //cpl
        var slider4 = jQuery('.slider4 .add').val(); //sales
        var slider5 = jQuery('.slider5 .add').val(); //revenue

        var slider1_decimal = parseFloat(slider1);
        var slider1_decimal_total = slider1_decimal.toFixed(2);

        //var monthly_management_fee = 1550;

        jQuery('#slider-1-total').html(addCommas(slider1_decimal_total));
        jQuery('#slider-2-total').html(addCommas(slider2));
        jQuery('#slider-3-total').html(slider3);
        jQuery('#slider-4-total').html(slider4);
        jQuery('#slider-5-total').html(addCommas(slider5));

        var visit_total = parseFloat(slider2) / parseFloat(slider1);
        var visit_total_no_decimal = visit_total.toFixed(0);
        jQuery('#visit').html(addCommas(visit_total_no_decimal));

        var leads_total = (parseFloat(visit_total) * parseFloat(slider3)) / 100;
        jQuery('#leads').html(addCommas(leads_total.toFixed(0)));

        var clp_total = parseFloat(slider2) / leads_total;
        jQuery('#cpl').html(clp_total.toFixed(0));
        
        var sales_total = parseFloat(visit_total) * (parseFloat(slider3)/100) * (parseFloat(slider4)/100);
        jQuery('#sales').html(addCommas(sales_total.toFixed(0)));

        var revenue_total = parseFloat(sales_total).toFixed(0) * parseFloat(slider5);
        jQuery('#revenue').html(addCommas(revenue_total));
        
        var investment = parseFloat(slider2); //3050
        var investment_total = ((parseFloat(revenue_total) - investment) / investment) * 100;

        jQuery('#total').html(addCommas(investment_total.toFixed(0)));

        
    }


    jQuery( ".calc-module" ).each(function() {  
        jQuery(this).find("#minus").click(function() {
            zoom("out");
        });

        jQuery(this).find("#plus").click(function() {
            zoom("in");
        });
    });


    function zoom(direction) {
    
        jQuery( ".calc-module .add" ).each(function() {
        
            var slider1 = jQuery(this).val(); //visit
            var slider = jQuery(this);
            var step = jQuery(this).attr('step');

            if (direction === "out") {
                newStepValue = parseFloat(slider1) - parseFloat(step); // working
            } else {
                newStepValue = parseFloat(slider1) + parseFloat(step); // working
            }

            slider.val(newStepValue).change();

            console.log();

        });    
        
    };









    function addCommas(x) {
        var parts = x.toString().split(".");
        parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return parts.join(".");
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget the fiddle?

Comment: oh thank you, I forgot to put it in @maganthro

Comment: You want each + and - to change the slider they're attached to, but they're actually changing all of them.. is that right?

Comment: that is correct @maganthro

Comment: For a start, you have given all the + buttons an id of 'plus', but ids must be unique. Secondly, you're telling your 'zoom' function to change every slider ('.calc-module .add'). You need to specify which one to change.

Comment: ok, so maybe I change #plus & #minus to class instead of ID for the second one, not really sure how to implement it @maganthro

Comment: I'm playing around with it now, but not finish it today. Basically, pass 'this' as a parameter to zoom(this, "out"), then find the slider inside it and change that one. Don't .each() over all the sliders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have moved your code to Fiddle and fixed. It is not the best fix but I think it works.

I found there following issues.

1. you have had multiple buttons with the same id - it was id="minus" and id="plus". I have changed it into class (so no id="minus" but class="minus")
2. when you were calling zoom function you didn't pass the context / slider which is being affected - I have fixed it.

To get button parent container I used `$(this).parent()` and changed zoom call to:

```
jQuery(this).find(".minus").click(function() {
    zoom("out", $(this).parent());
});
```

3. zoom function was not accepting the context / slider container which is being affected. Basically you were querying for every slider container group and change value.

I have changed it to:

```
function zoom(direction, sliderGroup) {
    jQuery( ".add", sliderGroup ).each(function() {
       // inner is left the same
    })
})
```

You can see that zoom function have second argument `sliderGroup` and this argument I am passing to jQuery query as query context (second parameter). This way this jQuery query function will only return all elements with class `add` in given `sliderGroup`.

Here you can see the Fiddle after changes https://jsfiddle.net/wo26pgd9/6/

If you have additional questions or this solution is not suitable for you, describe your case so I can suggest a better one.

Best regards
Łukasz

PS: I am new here - if I made something wrong please point me that out

Comment: Actually its working perfectly, I have implemented it on the website and its working, thank you @Łukasz Piotr Łuczak